# Unable to implement AJAX form submission (inline success) with deform_bootstrap

Tags: pyramid, pylons

I was trying to implement Ajax form submission as context given [AJAX Form Submission(inline success)](http://deformdemo.xo7.de/ajaxform/) but it is not working in my case, here is my code.

```
@view_config(route_name='add_user', permission='admin', renderer='add_user.mako')
def add_user(self):

   #adding succeed method as per given context in above link. 
    def succeed():
        return Response('<div id="thanks">Thanks!</div>')

    schema = UserSchema(validator = user_DoesExist).bind(request=self.request)
    #Form defined with use_ajax=True.
    form = deform.Form(schema, action=self.request.route_url('add_user'), buttons=('Add User','Cancel'), use_ajax=True)

    if 'Cancel' in self.request.params:
        return HTTPFound(location = self.request.route_url('home'))

    if 'Add_User' in self.request.params:
        appstruct = None
        try:
            appstruct = form.validate(self.request.POST.items())
        except deform.ValidationFailure, e:
            log.exception('in form validated')
            return {'form':e.render()}

        newuser = User(username=appstruct['username'], 
                       name=appstruct['name'], 
                       extension=appstruct['extension'], 
                       pin=appstruct['pin'], 
                       status=1)

        DBSession.add(newuser)
        DBSession.flush()
        return dict(form=form.render(success=succeed))
    return dict(form=form.render(appstruct={}))
```

**Output:**
*On form submission code gets executed but form on screen remains in unchanged but it does not execute succeed() method.* :(

And if try it with exactly same context as stated in the above link such as

```
@view_config(route_name='add_user', permission='admin', renderer='add_user.mako', name='ajaxform')
@demonstrate('AJAX form submission (inline success)')
def ajaxform(self):

    #adding succeed method as per given context in above link. 
    def succeed():
        return Response('<div id="thanks">Thanks!</div>')

    schema = UserSchema(validator = user_DoesExist).bind(request=self.request)
    #Form defined with use_ajax=True.
    form = deform.Form(schema, action=self.request.route_url('add_user'), buttons=('Add User','Cancel'), use_ajax=True)

    if 'Cancel' in self.request.params:
        return HTTPFound(location = self.request.route_url('home'))

    if 'Add_User' in self.request.params:
        appstruct = None
        try:
            appstruct = form.validate(self.request.POST.items())
        except deform.ValidationFailure, e:
            log.exception('in form validated')
            return {'form':e.render()}

        newuser = User(username=appstruct['username'], 
                       name=appstruct['name'], 
                       extension=appstruct['extension'], 
                       pin=appstruct['pin'], 
                       status=1)

        DBSession.add(newuser)
        DBSession.flush()
        return self.render_form(form, success=succeed)
    return dict(form=form.render(appstruct={}))
```

**Output:**
*NameError: name 'demonstrate' is not defined*

if i remove this line 
      @demonstrate('AJAX form submission (inline success)')

than i gives me **error**:

**AttributeError: 'UsersView' object has no attribute 'render_form'**

Need help to perform a ajax form submission using deform_bootstrap.

Thanks,

correct me if i am wrong somewhere. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.  The problem is that the form's render function doesn't actually take a success keyword argument i.e.

```
form.render(success='<div>here</div')
```

Isn't actually going to what you think.  If you look at the demo code you can see that they call another function

```
self.render_form(form, success='<div>here</div>')
```

This is a completely separate function to the form rendering function.  It process the call (let's assume a valid post) and then if the validation is success checks to see if 'success' is defined and returns that as the HTML in a response object.  Otherwise it returns 'form.render' in the response object.

Hope that helps.

Keith